# SQL Query to select posts from user and followed users is not including own posts

Tags: mysql, sql, database, posts

I'm building a query that should return the last 10 posts (default ordering) by `$userId` and the users it is following.

SQL Fiddle with a minimal example of the query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5ByFAXwADj5pfjCTn1g1m/2

The database structure is pretty simple:

```
posts (id, root, user, content)
users (id, username)
following (user_id, followed)
```

This is the query I'm currently using to get all posts:

```sql
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, users.id AS user_id, users.username
FROM posts
     LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user = users.id
WHERE LIMIT 10
```

The query is working but it is listing posts from every user without distinction.

This is the query I built to exclude posts from users that `$userId` is not following, but it doesn't include `$userId`'s own posts:

```sql
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, users.id AS user_id, users.username
FROM following
     LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.user = '$userId' OR posts.user = following.followed
     LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user = users.id
WHERE (following.user_id = '$userId' OR following.user_id = NULL) LIMIT 10
```

I've tried replacing the `LEFT JOIN posts` with an `INNER JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN` with no success whatsoever. I'm not able to find the error, why isn't the query including posts made by `$userId`?

I have also tried selecting from posts and joining followers, but it is returning duplicated content:

```sql
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, users.id AS user_id, users.username
FROM posts
     LEFT JOIN following ON following.user_id = '$userId'
     LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user = users.id
WHERE (posts.user = '$userId' OR posts.user = following.followed)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Done @Strawberry https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tao9a2gtpo9brgCwkKN3PJ/1

Comment: So that includes the desired result?

Comment: @HAlex it doesn't look like a _minimal_ example :) MCRE only includes what is important to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Strawberry see updated version here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tao9a2gtpo9brgCwkKN3PJ/3 no it does not include the desired result because I can't find a working query

Comment: @artoodetoo I'm really sorry, I should have put more time on that. I've updated the link where I removed unnecessary fields and sub-queries

Comment: One thing that I've noticed with the Fiddle is that using user_id 1 works, while user_id 2 returns nothing

Comment: 'it does not include the desired result because I can't find a working query' - in that case, the example is not minimal and complete

Comment: @HAlex *the last 10 posts by $userId and the users it is following* does this mean the users that $userId follows or the users that follow the $userId?

Comment: @forpas the users that $userId follows.

Comment: @Strawberry how can I add a working example if the working query is what I'm looking for?

Comment: And how are the *last 10 posts* determined? I don't see a date column. Is it the last 10 posts.id?

Comment: Yes, @forpas default ordering (by id) is ok. In the original question and query, I was ordering by a date column which I later removed for a simpler example.

Comment: @HAlex it is not clear do you want to get 10 records at all or 10 last records of _each_ of friend and the user himself. First is too simple as for me :) so, look at my answer about last 10 of the user and each of his/her friends.

Comment: You could ignore the 10 limit altogether, in this case I want to get 10 reconds in total, including user posts and posts by users he/she's following.

Comment: Well, everyone else manages to do it

Comment: @HAlex got it. ten-records-in-a-whole is what already answered by others. But I've already added different point of view, let it be :)

Comment: @artoodetoo sure, your answer is still interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to post a UNION solution

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    content,
    user_id,
    username
FROM
    (SELECT
        posts.id post_id,
        content,
        users.id user_id,
        username
    FROM
        posts INNER JOIN
            users
        ON user = users.id
    UNION SELECT
        posts.id,
        content,
        users.id,
        username
    FROM
        posts INNER JOIN (
            following INNER JOIN
                users
            ON user_id = users.id
        ) ON user = followed
    ) p
WHERE
    user_id = 1
LIMIT 10;
```

Then I saw @Gordon Linoff's solution which might be better - more concise, at least - but I don't think it works as posted.

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    content,
    users.id,
    username
FROM
    posts INNER JOIN
        users
    ON user = users.id
WHERE
    users.id = 1
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            following
        WHERE
            followed = user
            AND user_id = 1
    )
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This query does in fact seem to work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5ByFAXwADj5pfjCTn1g1m/3 I'll do some more testing...

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1):

> I'm building a query that should return the last 10 posts by $userId and the users it is following.

So, there are two tasks here:

1. Get first N records per group
2. Apply query to given user PLUS the same for the related users

I would do something like this (pseudo code):

```
ids = query('SELECT user_id FROM following WHERE followed = :id)', userId).pluck('user_id');
ids.push(userId);
```

```sql
SELECT x.id, x.user_id, x.content
FROM (
      SELECT  @num := IF(@id = user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS num, 
              @id := posts.user_id as x_user_id, 
              posts.*
      FROM 
          (SELECT @num := null, @id := null) x, 
          posts
      WHERE posts.user_id IN(:ids)
      ORDER BY posts.id DESC
) AS x
WHERE x.num <= 10
```

(https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aiBUwqDApJp6foyq13ZZ2u/1)

See:

- S.O.: [get first N records per group](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+get+first+N+per+group)
- S.O.: [prepared statement with WHERE IN](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+prepared+statement+with+WHERE+IN)

Comment: If I understand correctly if I follow 10K users my query string contains all 10K user IDs, is this right?

Comment: Yep. If you'd like to limit your newsfeed, add some additional condition. Like "have posted this week" or kind of.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much but it is not my intention to build a query string this way

Answer (score 1):

Get the posts from the table `posts` under your conditions and join to `users`:

```
select p.id, p.content, u.id AS user_id, u.username
from (
  select *
  from posts
  where user = '$user_id'
     or user in (select user_id from following where followed = '$user_id')
) p inner join users u on u.id = p.user  
order by p.id desc limit 10
```

Note that as it is your requirement the results may not contain posts by the user `'$user_id'` if the last 10 posts are from the users that this user follows.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2cc077dc897726f1969b361f4a979490).

Comment: Your query is working nice, hence I upvoted. But I cannot change the accepted answer until I understand which one has better performance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically want an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.content, u.id AS user_id, u.username
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     ON p.user = u.id
WHERE u.id <> ?   -- ? is the userid AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM following f
              WHERE f.followed = ? AND
                    f.user_id = u.id
             )
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your example doesn't seem to be working. It only includes posts by user_id 1 when testing with user n. 2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5ByFAXwADj5pfjCTn1g1m/1